# How to get instance id from the ami using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ec2, boto3

I wanted to get the **instance id** which creates the ami.I am using the below script-

```
    sess = Boto3Connecton.get_boto3_session(arn)
    elb_conn = sess.client(service_name='ec2', region_name=region)
    images = conn.describe_images(Owners=['self'])["Images"]
    for image in images:
        instance_id=image["InstanceId"]
        print "the instance which creates this ami is {0}".format(instance_id)
```

But the above script throws an exception message that "No InstanceId key Found" because the current function does not give information about the instance which create this ami.

Is there any way to determine the instance-id which creates that ami using amazon-boto3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no instance ID, and even if there were, what use would it be? The AMI was created some time in the past from a running or stopped EC2 instance, but the ID of that instance is immaterial.

You can see the specific properties available for an image [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_Image.html), for example architecture and creationDate.

It's probably worth asking: what are you actually trying to do here? Why do you think you need an instance ID?

Comment: I agree with you.I actually need to find the instance(id) which created that ami.

Comment: @anoop You cannot, as far as I know, get the instance ID after the fact. However, you are presumably the one who triggered the creation of the AMI so why don't you just modify that process to also record the source instance ID, for example as a tag on the new AMI? I still do not see why you'd want the instance ID - that's not a meaningful piece of data. I could, however, see why you might want to copy tags from the source instance to the AMI - that would make sense.

Comment: Thanku @jarmod. :) 
I actually need to copy all amis (which are created by an instance) to another region through Boto Call.

Comment: @anoop It's still not clear to me why instance ID is useful in this scenario but if you genuinely do need it then simply add it to the AMI as a tag (or keep an independent mapping in a database of AMI id to instance ID).

Comment: ,yes,you are right.Since I am not able to get instance id from ami meta data ,I added instance information in ami description.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])
for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type)
```

(found in [boto3 doc here](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html#checking-what-instances-are-running))

Answer (score 1):

You can look for whichever instance your IAM role can describe that happens to match your local hostname:

```
def get_ec2_instance_id():
    import socket
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION_NAME)
    for reservation in ec2_client.describe_instances()['Reservations']:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:
            if instance['PrivateDnsName'].startswith(hostname):
                return instance['InstanceId']
```